# DTLS and Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman

Tags: tls, diffie-hellman

In the DTLS handshake, the two parties involved in the communication must authenticate each other by means of certificates, and after that they perform an ephemeral Diffie-Hellman key exchange, with the public Diffie-Hellman keys signed with the keys of the certificates.

Why EDH is needed in this context? If each party knows the other party's public key, why can't one party chose a random key and send it to the other one? What kind of security adds EDH in this context?

Comment: Google 'perfect forward secrecy' if you need follow-up from the above.

Comment: Ok, so the only difference is that with EDH you get forward secrecy, that's right?

Comment: PFS is the security enhancement that EDH provides over DH.